# php multiple array form

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I am using Laravel with a responsive table. each row has a unique set of data along with one field that I wish to change. Once changed, I am wanting to then submit it to the database with the added data. I have complicated it a little by pulling data into the initial table from two sql tables, it then needs to be submitted to two tables depending on if it's paid in or paid out.
**This is my form**

```
<form name='verify' method='post'>
{{ csrf_field() }}
<table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="95%" cellspacing="0">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Date</th>
<th>Description</th>
<th>Paid Out</th>
<th>Paid In</th>
<th>Assign Property</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
@foreach ($tempupload as $bill)
@foreach ($select_properties as $props)
<td>{{$bill->BillDate}}</td>
<td>{{$bill->Description}}</td>
<td>{{$bill->PaidOut}}</td>
<td>{{$bill->PaidIn}}</td>
<td>
<select name='property[]' class='form-control'>
<option value='' disabled selected> Please Choose </option>
<option value='N/A'>Not aligned</option>
<option value='{{$props->uniqueid}}'>{{$props->prop_num.$props->name.', '.$props->street.', '.$props->postcode}}</option>
</select>
</td>
<input type='hidden' name='PaidOut[]' value='{{$bill->PaidOut}}' readonly>
<input type='hidden' name='PaidIn[]' value='{{$bill->PaidIn}}' readonly>
<input type='hidden' name='TempID[]' value='{{$bill->id}}' readonly>
<input type='hidden' name='propertymgr[]' value='{{$props->manager}}' readonly>
<input type='hidden' name='date[]' value='{{$bill->BillDate}}' readonly>
</tr>
@endforeach
@endforeach
</tbody>
<tr>
<td colspan='4'></td>
<td>
<input type='submit' value='Assign all values' name='submit' class='btn btn-success'></input>
</td>
</table>
</form>
```

**This is my backend**

```
  public function verify() {
            if(Request::input('submit')) {
                    $TempID = Request::input('TempID');
                    $i = 0;
                        foreach($TempID as $value) {
                                $property = Request::input('property');
                                $PaidIn = Request::input('PaidIn');
                                $PaidOut = Request::input('PaidOut');
                                $propertymgr = Request::input('propertymgr');
                                $date = Request::input('paymentdate');
                            if ($property == '') {
                                // We don't want to do anything as the information might not have been submitted correctly.
                            } elseif ($property == 'N/A') {
                                // Define if it's a payment or junk, cause we don't need no headers.
                                if ($PaidOut == 'Paid Out') {
                                    //If it's a header we just want to get rid of that.
                                        DB::table('TempUpload')->where('BillDate','=', 'Date')->delete();
                                }
                                    //Otherwise, it could just not be linked to a property. So, we need to separate In's and Out's
                                    if ($PaidIn == '') {
                                        //Assume its a Expense
                                        DB::table('expenses')->insert(array( 
                                            'amount' => $PaidIn,
                                            'property_id' => 'None', //No id required as it's not linked to a property
                                            'property_manager' => 'None',
                                            'date' => $date));
                                            $i++;
                                    } else {
                                        //Assume its income
                                        DB::table('income')->insert(array( 
                                            'amount' => $PaidIn,
                                            'property_id' => 'None', //No id required as it's not linked to a property
                                            'property_manager' => 'None',
                                            'date' => $date));
                                            $i++;
                                    }       
                            } else {
                                // Everything else can be put into the database. - Property linked
                                if ($PaidIn == '') {
                                    //Assume its a Expense
                                    DB::table('expenses')->insert(array( 
                                        'amount' => $PaidIn,
                                        'property_id' => $property,
                                        'property_manager' => $propertymgr,
                                        'date' => $date));
                                        $i++;
                                } else {
                                    //Assume its income
                                    DB::table('income')->insert(array( 
                                        'amount' => $PaidIn,
                                        'property_id' => $property, 
                                        'property_manager' => $propertymgr,
                                        'date' => $date));
                                        $i++;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                            // We're done here.
                            return redirect('/admin/upload')->with('success', $i." Payments have been assigned their properties"); 
                        } else {
                            //it failed yo!
                            return redirect('/admin/upload')->with('error', "Something went wrong, no idea what to do."); 
                        }
            }
```

and the foreach keeps failing If anyone has the knowledge to assist, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Its a broad question not a specific issue I think, what I can suggest that debug line by line to get the track i.e. print array before loop whether it has proper value or not, print other stuff to get the line where the code is breaking.

Comment: One thing, three conditions are using `=` instead of `==`.

Comment: the code appears to fail the foreach section foreach($TempID as $value) { - - is it because there are some times where only one value would be sent?